# I need to install gcc4.9 on ubuntu 20.04 | matlab mex

Tags: matlab, gcc, simulink, mex, s-function

On matlab, I was trying to run
`mex file.c`
but I got a warning and error message. Anyway, I think the problem is what the warning says:

> Warning: You are using gcc version '9.3.0'. The version of gcc is not
> supported. The version currently supported with MEX is '4.9.x'. For a
> list of currently supported compilers see:
> http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/current_release

.

Then, I tried to install gcc-4.9:
`sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9`
but there is no package candidate.

Comment: My experiences is that generally, the newer gcc's work with MATLAB mex, so unless the mex file does not work, ignore the warning. Also, you must have a very, very old version of MATLAB, as the current one supports 9.x.x

Answer (score 4):

```
cd /etc/apt or 
sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list
```

append this to sources.list:

```
deb http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main
deb http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
```

then

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9
```

Comment: I get the following error:

`W: GPG error: http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be veri
fied because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5 NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32`          
`E: The repository 'http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease' is not signed.`                      
`N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.`             
`N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.`
How can I make it signed?

Comment: You need to add the signing key for the repo.  See, for example, 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-handle-apt-key-and-add-apt-repository-deprecation-using-gpg-to-add-external-repositories-on-ubuntu-22-04